# 2 choice commands in one batch file getting mixed up

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

Example:

```
@echo off
goto menu1

:menu1
cls
echo Menu 1
echo.
echo Press "1" to start control panel
echo.
echo Press "2" to go to second menu
echo.
choice /c 12
if errorlevel ==2 goto menu2
if errorlevel ==1 goto control panel


:menu2
cls
echo Menu 2
echo.
echo Press "1" start msconfig
echo.
echo Press "2" to go to first menu
echo.
choice /c 12
if errorlevel ==2 goto menu1
if errorlevel ==1 goto msconfig


:control panel
cls
start control
goto menu1


:msconfig
cls
start msconfig
goto menu1
```

So if Im in **menu1** and I press 2 it will go to **menu2**.

If Im in **menu2** and I press 2 it will go to **menu1**,

but if Im in **menu2** and I press 1 to open msconfig, it instead opens control panel in **menu1** while **menu2** is still opened, why is this?

Comment: I can't repro the problem. Put a `PAUSE` command after the `Start Control` and `Start msconfig` commands so you can be sure what you think is happening is actually happening. Also, you should put a `Goto :EOF` statement after your `If Errorlevel` statements. Otherwise invalid, or improperly interpreted errorlevels will result in the following commands being executed, whether you intended that or not.

Comment: Putting a pause didn't work, and it wasn't clear to me where you want me to put the ```Goto :EOF```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can (should) to use the if command and not error level.
You will also need to get user input to a variable like this,
     set /p examplemenu1= Enter your choice^>
That will insert what the user has chosen to examplemenu1, then you use the if command.

I will show you a better way to write a menu and fix your problem. In this menu if someone enters nothing, nothing will happen.

```
@echo off
:start
:menu1
cls
echo.
echo.
echo Enter 1 and Press Enter to open control panel
echo.
echo Enter 2 and Press Enter to go menu 2
echo.
set /p menu1= Enter your choice then Press Enter^>
if "%menu1%" EQU "1" goto :open-control
if "%menu1%" EQU "2" goto :menu2
goto :menu1

:menu2
Cls
REM I will do the basics
echo Menu 2
echo Type 1 to open msconfig
echo.
echo Type 2 to go back to menu 1
echo.
set /p menu2= Enter your choice and press enter^>
if "%menu2%" EQU "1" goto :open-msconfig
if "%menu2%" EQU "2" goto :menu1
goto :menu2

:open-control
cls
start control
REM People will ping a invalid host to wait
REM But they don't know that you can just use localhost
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
goto :start

:open-msconfig
Cls
start msconfig
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
goto :start
```

Test this out and reply if it works for you.

Comment: I tried it out and I dont like using ```set /p``` instead of ```choice /c```  because when using ```set /p``` you have to press enter after typing a key, you can type a letter even though the only choices are numbers, and you can type multiple keys, Thanks but Id rather use choice, just because of all the problems that occur with ```set /p```.